# Xamarin Forms: Can't resolve SendDisappearingEventOnPause()

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin Forms app, I'm trying to use the `SendDisappearingEventOnPause()` method as mentioned in [Xamarin Bug #40722](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40722) and described in a pull request linked from that page.

The problem is that I can't "see" the `Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.AppCompat` namespace, despite my project referencing `Xamarin.Forms.Core` where it supposedly lies.

Here is the code:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.AppCompat;

namespace MyRandomApp
{
    public static class CompatSetup
    {
        public static void Setup()
        {
            var cfg = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>();
            cfg.SendDisappearingEventOnPause(false);
        }
    }
}
```

The specific errors I'm seeing are:

```
CS0234  The type or namespace name 'AppCompat' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

and

```
CS1061  'IPlatformElementConfiguration<Android, Application>' does not contain a definition for 'SendDisappearingEventOnPause' and no extension method 'SendDisappearingEventOnPause' accepting a first argument of type 'IPlatformElementConfiguration<Android, Application>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

If the problem is really a missing assembly reference, what specific assembly or NuGet package do I need to add? If something else, what am I missing?

Comment: What's the version of your Xamarin.Forms? Try to update your Xamarin.Forms version in Nuget Packages.

Comment: York Shen got it in one. I am on 2.3.3.180. It looks like SendDisappearingEventOnPause() was introduced ca. 2.3.4-pre1. Thanks.